# Create IMFMediaType using Windows.Media.MediaProperties namespace

Tags: windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

Since the namespaces in `Windows.Media` just use Media Foundation under the hood, I was hoping to create my codecs with the WinRT convenience methods (on `AudioEncodingProperties`, `VideoEncodingProperties`) and then convert them to `IMFMediaType`. But I cant figure out how to convert them:

```cpp
using namespace winrt::Windows::Media::MediaProperties;
constexpr auto TryQI = [](auto el)
{
    auto try1 = el.try_as<IMFMediaType>();
    WINRT_ASSERT(not try1);
    auto try2 = el.Properties().try_as<IMFMediaType>();
    WINRT_ASSERT(not try2);
};
TryQI(AudioEncodingProperties::CreateAac(48'000, 2, 128'000));
TryQI(VideoEncodingProperties::CreateUncompressed(MediaEncodingSubtypes::Bgra8(), 1920, 1080));
```

`AudioEncodingProperties.Properties` is a `IMap<winrt::guid,IInspectable>`. Does anyone know what to inspect the `IInspectable` values for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [IPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.ipropertyvalue) objects.

If you have this:

```
auto props = AudioEncodingProperties::CreateAac(48'000, 2, 128'000);
auto prop = props.Properties().Lookup(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND); // Mfapi.h
```

You can get the value behind like this:

```
auto value = prop.as<Windows::Foundation::IPropertyValue>().GetUInt32();
```

Or this (C++/WinRT):

```
auto value = winrt::unbox_value<UINT32>(prop);
```

And to get an `IMFMediaType` reference from that, you can use [MFCreateMediaTypeFromProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatemediatypefromproperties)  like this, here with C++/WinRT:

```
com_ptr<IMFMediaType> type;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMediaTypeFromProperties(
    props.as<IUnknown>().get(),
    type.put()));
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess `MFCreateMediaTypeFromProperties` gets the types from `IPropertyValue::Type`